# How to add a glass effect on views in android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles, android-background

[image: Glass UI]

How to achieve a glass-like effect on views in android like the one that can be seen in the provided picture?

Comment: So... what have you tried so far? Any codes? research?

Comment: have you tried  alpha(transparency) in gradient?